# How can I migrate a has_many / belongs_to relationship in rails to has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-migrations

I have an existing rails 6 application where I have two models:

```rb
class Reservation << ApplicationRecord
# ...
  has_many :charges
# ...
end
```

```rb
class Charge << ApplicationRecord
# ...
  belongs_to :reservation
# ...
end
```

I want to refactor it to this:

```rb
class Reservation << ApplicationRecord
# ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :charges
# ...
end
```

```rb
class Charge << ApplicationRecord
# ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reservation
# ...
end
```

What I want to know is how to write that migration? There's already data in the table, so I need to retain existing charges whose reservation IDs are set and keep the link.

Comment: Caveat: I'm a total rails newbie, so if I'm specifying the destination state wrong, please tell me. Note that I did not write the initial models, so ... trust me that I can't just up and change the starting point or existing data.

Comment: It should be plural `has_and_belongs_to_many :reservations` ([docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)).

Comment: Thanks! Still doesn't solve my migration question, but at least it's less wrong :D

Comment: I recommend against HBTM. It's hard to expand. I'd recommend using a join model, which will have it's own class, and potentially additional fields, common ones being `order` and `status`. You'll end up with the same access methods, but you'll have a model in the middle that you can refer to directly and use to say more about the relationship between the two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful here, and make sure you can revert if there's a mistake, so you don't lose your data!

First you need to create the join table with a migration. You can create the migration from the command-line with:

```
rails g migration create_charges_reservations
```

this should create the template of the migration for you in db/migrate, which you'll populate according to your need like this:

```rb
class CreateChargesReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table charges_reservations do |t|
      t.integer :charge_id
      t.integer :reservation_id
    end
  end
end
```

run the migration from the command line:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Now make a join model:

```rb
# app/models/charges_reservation.rb
class ChargesReservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :charge
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

Now you have to migrate the existing data, so from the rails console:

```
Charge.all.each{|c| ChargesReservation.create(charge_id: c.id, reservation_id:c.reservation_id)}
```

And finally change the associations to habtm associations as you have indicated in your question

```rb
# charge.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :reservations

#reservation.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :charges
```

Oh and you can delete the reservation_id column in the charges table with another migration, once you are sure everything is working correctly. This is the point where you could create a problem b/c you're destroying data, so be sure that the join table was correctly populated.

You actually don't need the join model any longer either, it was just a convenient way to populate the join table. So you can delete the charges_reservation.rb model.

Comment: Is it necessary to always do the data migration in the console? It looked to me like the migration could also move the data... is that a bad idea? I'm asking specifically because I'm concerned that other users of the site code will get bitten by the migration moving the data.

Comment: I have frequently moved the data in migrations, without running into trouble. It's a convenience, b/c it gives you a way to migrate your production data too. However there are frequent warnings against it, and I'm not sure what the problem scenario is. So my suggestion would be to try it in your dev environment and if you don't run into trouble, do it on the production server.